# Does Azure trial version support , REST api for event query?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have created trail account with Azure (Default directory).
For authentication I'm using the below endpoint-1 ,after authentication when I was trying for an access for activity logs of Azure using REST API mentioned below endpoint-2.

So I'm getting an error :
ERROR : { "error": { "code": "AuthorizationFailed", "message": "The client '52822c14-3f4a-4273-ad38-b1c746f1fbd9' with object id '52822c14-3f4a-4273-ad38-b1c746f1fbd9' does not have authorization to perform action 'microsoft.insights/eventtypes/values/read' over scope '/subscriptions/0b618ac0-b3e7-49f3-9205-07660b77252d' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials." } }

Auth URL(endpoint-1) : https://login.windows.net/****************/oauth2/token

ActivityLog API (endpoint-2) : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/*******************/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2020-01-01T20:00:00Z'

Comment: So you want to get all Activity Log of your Azure subscription but got AuthorizationFailed error right ?

Comment: @StanleyGong Yes I'm trying to pull activity data through REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your exception info, it is obvious that your app: `52822c14-3f4a-4273-ad38-b1c746f1fbd9` has no permission to pull activity logs of your Azure subscription. I can repro this issue on my side too.

To solve this issue, you should assign a proper Azure subscription Role which has permission to pull logs. For instance, if you just want to pull logs using this app , you can assign Reader Role to it on Azure portal:

[image]
[image]

With this step is done, get a new access token and you can pull the logs you need :
[image]

If you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know .

Comment: Thank you @StanleyGong. It's working fine for me now :)  
I was not aware about 'app name' Permissions. Btw thanks one again.

Comment: Hi @RohitH , glad to know that your issue has been solved, so could you pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark this answer so that it will help others who has similar issues and it will be an award for me : ) have a nice day !